# How to read a text file from any directory and dialog in java?

Tags: java, file, classpath, inputstream, fileinputstream

I'm creating a game and level editor where levels are stored in .txt files.  On opening, the app opens a dialog to choose a file.  This works perfectly except it can't read files from outside the classpath.  What is a simple way to make it able to read a file from outside the classpath?

For getting the file I use:

```
public void getLevelPath() {
    FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog((Frame) null, "Select File to Open");
    dialog.setDirectory("C://");
    dialog.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    String file = dialog.getFile();
    System.out.println(file + " chosen.");
    levelPath = file;
}
```

And for reading I use:

```
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use a FileInputStream: InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);

Comment: Why not use a File Chooser instead of a File Dialog? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: For one, FileDialog is AWT, which became out of date about twenty years ago. I doubt it having been put in JavaFX, as they did with Swing's FileChooser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File inputFile = new File(path);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile );
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Comment: I'm getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: lvl01-1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: @yaskokai log and check the 'path' variable, it's must relative or absolute filepath url

Comment: I tried using getDirectory() and getAbsolutePath() but I still get the file not found error

Comment: @yaskokai test using  getDirectory() + getFile()